# ASP.NET Core MVC ActionFilter execute before AuthorizationFilter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, action-filter

On my site I have a few `controller`s that are restricted to authenticated users. Beyond that, there are a few of those controllers that require authentication, that ALSO need to be restricted based on the time of year.

To handle that, I created a `TimeRangeFilter` `ActionFilter`/`ResourceFilter`.

Here's what it looks like:

```
public class TimeRangeFilter : Attribute, IActionFilter, IOrderedFilter
{
  public string AllowedMonths { get; set; } // like |3|4|5|
  public string RedirectUrl { get; set; }
  ...... // OnActionExecuting....
}
```

Then, on my `Controller`'s `class`, I implement like this:

```
[TimeRangeFilter(AllowedMonths = "|3|4|", RedirectUrl = "/feature/welcome", Order = 1)]
[Authorize]
[IsNotNefarious]
public class HubController : BaseController
{...}
```

But, even with the `IOrderedFilter` `interface` on the `filter`, the `AuthorizationFilter` executes first, THEN my `TimeRangeFilter`.

For this welcome page, I don't want to require the user to be logged in to see it. But I don't want to have to change the URL that gets to my Hub page based on those allowed months.

How do I prioritize my `ActionFilter`/`ResourceFilter` to execute, and short-circuit, prior to the `AuthorizationFilter` execution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer is "You can't make `ActionFilter` execute before `AuhtorizeFilter`". But you can turn `TimeRangeFilter` into authorization filter

```
public class TimeRangeFilterAttribute : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter, IOrderedFilter
{
    public string AllowedMonths { get; set; } // like |3|4|5|
    public string RedirectUrl { get; set; }

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (not allowed) {
            context.Result = new RedirectResult(RedirectUrl);
        }
    }
}
```

Specify `Order = 0` to make it run before other `Authorize` checks, or try **not** implement `IOrderedFilter` for it and it will be executed first as well.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks. So even though it's using an AuthorizationFilter, I don't need to do any kind of "User.IsAuthenticated" or anything like that....sounds good!

Answer (score 4):

The solution from @Alexander does no longer work in .NET Core 3.1; now the `Authorize` attribute is being evaluated in the `AuthorizationMiddleware`, many steps before the filters are hit.

The best new approach is to make a custom middleware yourself, insert it after `UseRouting();` in startup, and let it query the endpoint information manually. Example:

```
public class TimeRangeAttribute : Attribute {
    public string Info { get; set; }
}

public class TimeRangeMiddleware {
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    public TimeRangeMiddleware(RequestDelegate next) => _next = next;

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context) {
        var endpoint = context.GetEndpoint();
        if (endpoint?.Metadata.GetMetadata<TimeRangeAttribute>() != null) {
            // check allowed or not
        }
        if(_next != null) await _next(context);
    }
}

// In Startup
public void Configure(...) {
    // ....
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseMiddleware<TimeRangeMiddleware>();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Oh snap! Thanks for this comment. It's an old question of mine, but I'm literally in the middle of upgrading to ASP.NET Core 3.1, and was going to release in the next couple weeks. Now I need to go back thru and make sure/fix all of these controllers that implement my TimeRangeFilter. THANK YOU! I'm upvoting for this!

Comment: I just found that in 3.1 there is an extension method to get the endpoint more easily, I updated the code above.